# Additional binding for keyboard-quit doesn't work with minibuffer

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer

I set `(global-set-key (kbd "H-g") 'keyboard-quit)`.

When the minibuffer is open and waiting for input, and I want to quit out of it, when I hit `H-g`, the bell rings and I see the Quit message, but the minibuffer remains open and accepting input. `C-g` works as expected: closes the minibuffer.

How can I make `H-g` quit the minibuffer?

Comment: Use `keyboard-escape-quit` instead.

Comment: When in the minibuffer, `C-g` calls `abort-recursive-edit` (you can see this via `C-h k C-g` when in the minibuffer).  That's another command you can consider.  However, there are a *lot* of minibuffer maps (try `M-x apropos minibuffer map`), and I'm not sure which ones inherit from which.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Is there a way I can simply alias `H-g` to `C-g` such that `H-g` will do whatever `C-g` does in the current context?

Comment: More details about this topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/fk1kow/weekly_tipstricketc_thread/fkvau9x/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to #emacs, I learned that `(global-set-key (kbd "H-g") (kbd "C-g"))` will work for this. C-g runs whatever command it is bound to, and now H-g will run a keyboard macro that consists of C-g, so it does exactly whatever C-g would.

A slight oddity is that because H-g is now bound to a keyboard macro, after hitting it, I see the keyboard macro message "After 0 kbd macro iterations: Quit", because that's exactly what it's doing -- quitting.

Comment: i was searching exactly for aliasing `Ctrl-G` and your solution helped.... thanks a ton, dear...

Comment: If this is the answer, OP, please consider accepting it.